# Clojure REPL в Vim

Tags: python, vim, clojure

Vim имеет набор плагинов для python и clojure (fireplace).

При попытке подключиться к *repl* (`:Connect nrepl://localhost:55555`), Vim выдает ошибку:

> Python interface not working.

Как спасти ситуацию?

Comment: Может дело в том, что вы подключаетесь к `locelhost` вместо `localhost`?

Comment: Опечатался когда тут код набирал.

Comment: UPD :echo has('python') возвращает 0. Питон установлен корректно. Win 7x64